# Running JavaMail API in Gradle Project on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have a Gradle project in my Eclipse IDE and I need to be able to send an e-mail receipt as part of a school project. I looked at this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm to try and create the most basic e-mail. I've tried the "sending a simple e-mail" example and I got this as my error:

```
Usage - java org.mortbay.jetty.Main [<addr>:]<port>
Usage - java org.mortbay.jetty.Main [<addr>:]<port> docroot
Usage - java org.mortbay.jetty.Main [<addr>:]<port> -webapp myapp.war
Usage - java org.mortbay.jetty.Main [<addr>:]<port> -webapps webapps
Usage - java -jar jetty-x.x.x-standalone.jar [<addr>:]<port>
Usage - java -jar jetty-x.x.x-standalone.jar [<addr>:]<port> docroot
Usage - java -jar jetty-x.x.x-standalone.jar [<addr>:]<port> -webapp myapp.war
Usage - java -jar jetty-x.x.x-standalone.jar [<addr>:]<port> -webapps webapps
```

I'm guessing I don't have the JavaMail API and Java Activation Framework (JAF) properly installed. I've followed some guides on how to do that. What I've done was right click gradle project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries tab -> Add External JARs.. And I added the JAF and JavaMail jar files (activation-1.1.1.jar and mail-1.4.5.jar). I also added

```
compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.5'
compile group: 'javax.activation', name: 'activation', version: '1.1.1'
```

to my build.gradle file. Any help on how to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I used.

```
// File Name SendEmail.java

import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendEmail
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
 {    
      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
  String to = "abcd@gmail.com";

  // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
  String from = "web@gmail.com";

  // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
  String host = "localhost";

  // Get system properties
  Properties properties = System.getProperties();

  // Setup mail server
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

  // Get the default Session object.
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

  try{
     // Create a default MimeMessage object.
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

     // Set From: header field of the header.
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

     // Set To: header field of the header.
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

     // Set Subject: header field
     message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

     // Now set the actual message
     message.setText("This is actual message");

     // Send message
     Transport.send(message);
     System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
  }catch (MessagingException mex) {
     mex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: post your code whatever you have written so far to send an email.

Comment: I used the exact same code provided in the tutorial link in my post.

Comment: Your error doesn't seem to have anything to do with JavaMail. It looks like the error you get when you start Jetty (a Java webserver) with incorrect arguments. You might want to describe how you are trying to start your application, and the type of Eclipse project you are using.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm not sure how I'm running Jetty but with my application I'm using a Gradle project.

Comment: So, how exactly are you trying to run your application (which commandline, or which Eclipse options)?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Okay got it to run by doing run as -> java application. But now I get the error "Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:"

Comment: That error is not surprising as it is unlikely you have a SMTP server running on localhost.

Comment: Is there a way to get it running? I'm on WIndows 10 and there are no tutorials online explaining how to get it done on 10 but they have it for older versions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give proper settings to send email. like

```
String host = "localhost";  // instead of localhost you have to give your hostname.
```

If you want to send mail via gmail, use the following code:

**SendEmail.java**

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendEmail{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "username@gmail.com";
        final String password = "password";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from-email@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("to-email@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Welcome Message");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Mail Sent Successfully");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this code and it tells me to log into my browser and try again even though I'm logged into the e-mail address in my browser.

Comment: Have you signed-in to the gmail with the same email id and password which you are providing in the following fields :
**`final String username = "username@gmail.com";`**  
**`final String password = "password";`** And your **`"from-email@gmail.com"`** also should be same as your username.

Comment: Yes I did all that.